# Big-theta asymptotic limit of expression involving incomplete beta function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, beta-function

**I'm having trouble finding the Big-Theta asymptotic limit of expression involving incomplete beta function.**

$S(k,k)=k\big(\frac{1}{\delta_1}-\frac{1}{\delta_2}\big)+2k^2\dbinom{2k}{k}\bigg[\frac{I_x(k,k+1)}{\delta_2}-\frac{I_x(k+1,k)}{\delta_1}\bigg]$

where

$I_x(k,k+1)$ and $I_x(k+1,k)$ are normalized incomplete beta functions with $x=\frac{\delta_1}{\delta_1+\delta_2}$

Remark: $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ are constant and $k\in \mathbb Z_{\geq1}$

Comment: The formulae $$
I_x (k,k + 1) = \sum\limits_{j = k}^{2k} \binom{2k}{j}x^j (1 - x)^{2k - j} 
$$ and $$
I_x (k + 1,k) = 1 - I_{1 - x} (k,k + 1)
$$ could be useful.

Comment: @Gary, Thank you for your help. I'll try to use it.

Comment: Is there any relationship between hypergeometric functions and incomplete beta that you could use ?

Comment: See https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.ii Also the asymptotics in http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.18.E9 may be useful.